How to use pool for redis connection with express-session and connect-redis
I am having some problems with sockets. I'm using express-session to manage session and it is storing session on redis.
I want to use pool for connections of redis. Express session uses RedisStore and RedisStore needs RedisClient, I cannot give it pool instead of RedisClient,
My Code :
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const session = require('express-session')
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis').default

var redisClient  = new Redis({ host: `redis`, port: 6379 })

redisClient.on('ready', () => { console.log(`Redis is ready @${redisClient.options.host}`)})
redisClient.on('error', (err) => { console.log('Redis error: ', err) })

const sessionAge = 24 * 60 * 1000

module.exports = session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  key: 'sid',
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  rolling: false,
  cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: sessionAge, sameSite: 'lax' },
  expires: sessionAge
})


I've found a way to create a fake RedisStore that does Redis transactions using the methods I created.
const session = require('express-session')
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis').default
const { RedisPool } = require('ioredis-conn-pool')

let pool = new RedisPool({
    redis: {
      host: `redis`,
      port: 6379
    },
    pool: {
      min: 10,
      max: 100
    }
  })

const redisStore = new RedisStore({ client: {} })

const noop = (_err, _data) => {}

redisStore.get = async function (sid, cb = noop) {
  const key = this.prefix + sid
  let redisClient
  try {
    redisClient = await pool.getConnection()
    const data = await redisClient.get(key)
    if (!data) return cb()
    return cb(null, await this.serializer.parse(data))
  } catch (err) {
    return cb(err)
  } finally {
    if (redisClient) {
      await pool.release(redisClient)
    }
  }
}

redisStore.set = async function (sid, sess, cb = noop) {
  const key = this.prefix + sid
  const ttl = this._getTTL(sess)
  let redisClient
  try {
    const val = this.serializer.stringify(sess)
    if (ttl > 0) {
      redisClient = await pool.getConnection()
      if (this.disableTTL) {
        await redisClient.set(key, val)
      } else {
        const isRedis = 'scanIterator' in redisClient
        if (isRedis) {
          await redisClient.set(key, val, { EX: ttl })
        } else {
          await redisClient.set(key, val, 'EX', ttl)
        }
      }
      return cb()
    } else {
      return this.destroy(sid, cb)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return cb(err)
  } finally {
    if (redisClient) {
      await pool.release(redisClient)
    }
  }
}

redisStore.destroy = async function (sid, cb = noop) {
  const key = this.prefix + sid
  let redisClient
  try {
    redisClient = await pool.getConnection()
    await redisClient.del([key])
    return cb()
  } catch (err) {
    return cb(err)
  } finally {
    if (redisClient) {
      await pool.release(redisClient)
    }
  }
}

redisStore.touch = async function (sid, sess, cb = noop) {
  const key = this.prefix + sid
  if (this.disableTouch || this.disableTTL) return cb()
  let redisClient
  try {
    redisClient = await pool.getConnection()
    await redisClient.expire(key, this._getTTL(sess))
    return cb()
  } catch (err) {
    return cb(err)
  } finally {
    if (redisClient) {
      await pool.release(redisClient)
    }
  }
}

const sessionAge = 24 * 60 * 1000

module.exports = session({
  store: redisStore,
  key: 'sid',
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  rolling: false,
  cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: sessionAge, sameSite: 'lax' },
  expires: sessionAge
})

